# Java [Basic] Object Issues

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Apologies for vague title as i couldn't think what the name is.

Basically creating a small program that calculates a students financial payment.
When i run it, it calculates the object allowance no problem.
However whatever i try the object 'Bursary' doesn't seem to come up with anything aside 0.

The code is as follows :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class studentFinance implements Payment {
    private String stuname, department, course;
    private float budget, allowance, bursary;
    private int id, currentbudget, attendance;
    private double numbofcourses;

    // student name, id, department, course enrolledon, attendance, bursary,allowance

    //course and numbofcourses already read in
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public studentFinance(float currentBudget) {
        budget = currentbudget;
    }

    public float amendBudget(float newbudget) {
        budget = newbudget;//Transfer data from parameter to instance variable
        return budget;//Return statement
    }

    public float calcPayment() {
        //stuname,department,numbofcourses,attendance,id

        System.out.println("Please enter the student name");
        stuname = in.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the department name");
        department = in.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of numbofcourses");
        numbofcourses = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the attendance");
        attendance = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter their ID number");
        id = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter HND,HNC or NC");
        course = in.next();

        if (attendance > 95 & numbofcourses >= 6) {
            allowance = 1000;
        } else if (attendance > 85 & numbofcourses >5) {
            allowance = (1000 * .75F);
        } else if (attendance > 75 & numbofcourses >= 4) {
            allowance = (1000 * .5F);
        } else if (attendance > 75 & numbofcourses >= 3) {
            allowance = 100;
        } else {
            allowance = 0;
        }

        if(course=="HND") {
            bursary = 250;
        } else if(course=="HNC") {
            bursary = 200;
        } else if(course=="NC") {
            bursary = 100;
        } else {
            bursary = 0;
        }

        return bursary + allowance;
    } 

    double payment;

    public void makePayment() {
        System.out.println("The allowance total is : " + payment);
        payment = bursuary + allowance;
    }

    public void print() {

    }


}
```

If it isany use this is the code used for the interface , theirs other elements to it but i don't think they are relevant here.

```
interface Payment {
    public float amendBudget(float budget);
    public float calcPayment();
    public void  makePayment();
    public void  print();
}
```

Regards for any help.

Comment: Does this even compile? You reference a variable "bursuary" I assume it should reference "bursary"

Comment: Indeed a good point, have changed it on compiling i noticed this.

Comment: Couple style-related things: interfaces don't need the `public` declaration on methods as it's implied for all interface methods.  Also, class names should generally be CamelCase, so your class should probably be called StudentFinance.  Variables are generally camelCase (lower first char), which you use sometimes but not all the time.  This doesn't change the behavior of the code, but conforming to the Java style standards makes it easier to read for most people who are familiar with those standards already.

Comment: @HertenFerford Plz mark the answer as accepted answer , if you satisfy with below answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` doesn't do what you think it does here.  `==` (when applied to objects) just checks to see if two objects are the same object, not if their contents are equivalent, so it doesn't work for strings here.  What you want is:

```
if("HND".equals(course)) {
  // ...
} else if ("HNC".equals(course)) {
  // ...
} // etc
```

Generally you only want to use `==` when dealing with primitives (`int`, `float`, etc), *or* you explicitly just want to see if two variables point to exactly the same object.

You could also write them as:

```
if(course.equals("HND")) {}
```

but I prefer to use `.equals` on the constants as you know they will never be `null`.  It's probably not a concern for you here, but it's just the pattern I've gotten used to.

Comment: Cheers for that , a great help funnily enough person beside me figured it out at the same tim.

Answer (score 3):

you should use .equals instead of == when comparing the strings here:

```
    else if(course=="HNC")
    {
      bursary = 200;
    }

    else if(course=="NC")
        {
            bursary = 100;
        }
   else

    {
        bursary = 0;
    }
```